# Android scrollable calendar with full year

Tags: android, calendarview

I stuck on a CalendarView, I need to do something like:

[image: http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2187/2187086/scroll-calendar-400300-0-s-307x512.jpg]

How can I achieve this? Calling instance for each month is obviously bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own calendar view using a ListView where each Item on your ListView is a month, you don't need to instantiate each month with the ListView, you will only instantiate like 3 or 4 months  depending on your implementation.