# Calendar in Listview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want Calendar in listview. I have taken gridview inside Listview but not able to populate different months .Without using Time Square lib i want to achieve this.
[Android scrollable calendar with full year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137186/android-scrollable-calendar-with-full-year)

```
public class ListviewCalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String [] result;
    Context context;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ListviewCalendarAdapter(SelectDateActivity selectDateActivity, String[] numberList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        context=selectDateActivity;
        result=numberList;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
       GridView gridView;
        TextView textViewMonth, textViewExceptDate;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_select_calendar, null);
        holder.gridView=(GridView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_calendar);
        holder.textViewMonth=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.month);
       // holder.textViewExceptDate=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.exceptDate);
        holder.textViewMonth.setText(result[position]);

       Calendar _calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       int month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
      int  year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        holder.gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewCalendarAdapter(context,R.id.textViewNumber,_calendar));

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " +result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}

     public static String[] monthList = {"July 2016", "August 2016", "September 2016"};

Calling listview-->

    listViewCalendar = (CustomListview) findViewById(R.id.listview_calendar);
            listViewCalendar.setAdapter(new ListviewCalendarAdapter(this, monthList));
```

Comment: can you provide a simple sketch or a screenshot of your xml file?

Comment: @CoolGuyCG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137186/android-scrollable-calendar-with-full-year link is mentioned above..

Comment: Include information from link as they tend to die, go stale etc...